# toastr not showing when imported in a jsx file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, toastr

I have a react app that uses webpack to bundle JS and CSS into 1 file and output it into a destination folder. I've recently added toastr to 1 of my jsx file:

```
import toastr from "toastr";
import "toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
```

Running the app and viewing the source, i've verified in the browser (viewing the source files) that toastr.min.js is included in the JS bundle and toastr.min.css is included in the CSS bundle. However, the toastr notification doesn't show. There is no error and a scrollbar appears in the right-side for a few seconds so I suspected the toastr code is working, just that the CSS is not properly styling for some reason.

I removed this line:

```
import "toastr/build/toastr.min.css"
```

and then directly added this to html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/toastr.min.css" />
```

and now it works. But I want to make it work where toastr.min.css is included in the bundle. Is there anything I'm missing?

**webpack config**

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const miniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        home: "./Scripts/Components/Home/main.js",
        login: "./Scripts/Components/Login/main.js",
        vendor: [
            "jquery",
            "react",
            "react-dom",
            "react-router-dom",
            "react-css-modules",
        ]
    },

    mode: "development",

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    chunks: "all",
                    name: "vendor",
                    test: "vendor",
                    enforce: true
                }
            }
        }
    },

    output: {
        publicPath: "/js/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "/wwwroot/js/"),
        filename: "[name].bundle.js"
    },

    devtool: "source-map",

    plugins: [
        new miniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "../css/[name].css"
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["env", "react"]
                }
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [{
                loader: miniCssExtractPlugin.loader,                        
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader",
                query: {
                    modules: true,
                    localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you using any webpack plugins that can potentially be a problem here?

Comment: Are you using loaders for css in webpack.config.js?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything i'm using that can cause a problem, I've posted my whole webpack config

Comment: Hi, did you fix this?